# Image Effects keep on rendering

Tags: ios, mobile, unity-game-engine, image-effects

I am using Unity 5 and the image effects provided by Unity. When I apply an effect such as Twirl or Vortex to Camera, it keeps on rendering and in the case of these 2 image effects, it keeps on rotating image from the center. This happens when I am testing on iOS device. If I test it in Unity Editor, it works fine. How can I stop this issue? So that rendering is done once. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you're not rotating the camera or something? These effects inherently only process ONCE what is rendered by the camera each frame.

Comment: I found the problem. My camera's clear flags was set to nothing. Once i set to clear skybox, it works fine now.

Comment: Glad you got it to work. Good luck!